# Video from firefox OS phone plays back sideways

Tags: javascript, video, firefox-os

If I take a video using a firefox OS phone (Geeksphone Peek running stable 1.1), and download it to a computer, it plays back sideways (vlc).  It doesn't play back sideways from the actual gallery though.

The strange thing is, if I try to open that same video from a url with the mozactivity API:

```
var activity = new MozActivity({
  name: "view",
  data: {
    type: [
      "video/webm",
      "video/mp4",
      "video/3gpp",
      "video/youtube"
    ],
    url: "https://foo.bar/video.3gpp"
  }
```

});

To stream it through the gallery, it WILL play back sideways.  Is this a known bug anywhere or could someone explain to me why this could happen?

Comment: I tried it on my Geeksphone Peak with Firefox 1.1, and I had no problem: the video was playing well. How did you download the file? Can you put the video somewhere so we can download it to check please?

Comment: Here you go:
http://oliphaunts.com/test.3gp

Answer (score 2):

This is not FirefoxOS-specific, iOS videos are also displayed sideways in vlc for me. I think this is a known problem with both vlc and gstreamer-based video players, like totem. See here for a bug report on Ubuntu's video player with references to gstreamer's upstream bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gstreamer0.10/+bug/697756

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce this behavior at all. I'll try to find someone who can help, but may I suggest you to take a look at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/, and maybe submit something there as it seems like a bug.